# Need help installing qt_spim

Tags: system-installation

Trying to do my homework but can't even manage to install the simulator to start working on it.

I followed the steps on the spim website and downloaded the debian file but don't know how to compile it for my system.

I've managed to install the base spim but still can't get qt_spim.

I did "sudo apt-get install spim" to get the base spim and then tried "sudo apt-get install qt_sdk" to install qtspim from a thread in 2013 but this doesn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using `apt-cache search` shows us:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ apt-cache search spim
spim - MIPS R2000/R3000 emulator
walt@bat:~(0)$ apt-cache search qtspim
walt@bat:~(0)$ apt-cache search qt_spim
walt@bat:~(0)$ apt-cache search qt_sdk
walt@bat:~(0)$ apt-cache search qt-sdk
qt-sdk - Complete Qt Software Development Kit
```

It seems the package you want is `qt-sdk`, not `qt_sdk`.